# why ByteArray failed?

Tags: solidity

TypeError: Unary operator - cannot be applied to type bytes1
return a>-b;
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use indexing `[index]` on byte array `bytes1` like this

```
    bytes1 a = 0x67;
    bytes1 b = 0x68;
    function c() public view returns (bool) {
        return a[0] >= b[0];
    }
```